# What is off-diagonal long range order in superfluid?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, superfluidity

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states):

> *[...]Off-diagonal long-range order (ODLRO) [...] exists whenever there is a macroscopically large factored component (eigenvalue) in a reduced density matrix of any order.*

How to understand the ODLRO in superfluidity?

Answer (score 15):

The one-body density matrix is defined by

$\rho(r,r')=\langle \hat\psi^\dagger (r) \hat\psi (r')\rangle$.

ODLRO is equivalent to say that $\lim_{|r-r'|\to \infty}  \rho(r,r') \neq 0$ and in the case of (bosonic) superfluids this corresponds to

$\lim_{|r-r'|\to \infty}  \rho(r,r')=\langle \hat\psi^\dagger (r) \rangle\langle\hat\psi (r')\rangle$.

You can see that the $U(1)$ symmetry $\hat\psi (r)\to e^{i\theta} \hat\psi (r)$ is then spontaneously broken by the anomalous average $\langle\hat\psi (r)\rangle \neq 0$.

In a homogeneous system $\langle\hat\psi (r)\rangle$ is independent of $r$ by translation symmetry and $n_0=\langle \hat\psi^\dagger (r) \rangle\langle\hat\psi (r')\rangle$ defines the condensate density of the Bose-Einstein condensate.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain in more detail why is $U(1)$ symmetry broken by the  anomalous average $\langle\hat\psi (r)\rangle \neq 0$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian is invariant under the transformation $\hat \psi^{(\dagger)}\to e^{(-)i\theta} \hat \psi^{(\dagger)}$, so one would expect that all averages implying only annihilation operators should vanish $\langle \hat \psi\rangle=\langle \hat \psi^2\rangle=...=0$ by symmetry. Therefore, if $\langle \hat \psi\rangle\neq 0$, this mean that the symmetry is broken. Its called spontaneously, because the Hamiltonian does not break the symmetry, only the ground-state of the system.

Comment: Can you please write down the Hamiltonian?

Comment: You can have a look at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate

Comment: @Adam: ODLRO, as you say, implies a non-vanishing value of the one-particle density matrix as $r \rightarrow \infty$; the value it takes is the condensate density. So in a superfluid without Bose-Einstein condensation, there should be no ODLRO.

Comment: @MaviPranav: Yes, sure. What's your point ? To make your comment (and my reply) useful : In 2D bosonic superfluid at finite temperature, there is no condensate density, thus no NDLRO, but there is quasi-NDLRO, that is $\lim_{|r-r'|\to \infty}\rho(r,r')\to 1/|r-r'|^\alpha$, with $\alpha>0$, contrary to a normal fluid where the decay would be exponential.

Comment: @Adam: That the concept of ODLRO is more rightly applicable to BEC, and not necessarily to superfluidity (unless BEC drives the latter as in helium-4). Probably my comment was aimed more at the poster i.e. I'm not sure if ODLRO has any relevance to a superfluid per se.

Comment: @Adam Could you please explain for boson superfluid case, $\langle \psi \psi \rangle = \langle \psi \rangle \langle\psi\rangle$?

Comment: @Blue: not sure what you expect as an "explanation". Generally, an average $\langle A(r) B(0)\rangle= G_{AB}(r)+\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle$ with $G_{AB}(r)$ a correlation function that goes to $0$ as $r\to\infty$ (either exponentially or algebraically). By definition, there is long range order if $\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle\neq 0$.

Comment: @Adam Adam, thanks for your answer. However, it is not obvious to me why $G_{AB}(r) = \langle(A(r)-\langle A\rangle)(B(0)-\langle B\rangle)\rangle\rightarrow 0$ if $r\rightarrow0$. I thought long range order means $G_{AB}\neq 0$ previously.

Comment: @Blue that's just a physical statement. At long distance, you expect that two points at long distance to be uncorrelated

Comment: @Adam In your answer, $\rho(r,r^\prime)$ is referred to as the one-body density matrix. Is it some reduced density matrix for an interacting many-body system? Also, what is the interpretation of $\hat{\psi}(r)$?

Comment: Yes. In first quantization, it is obtained from the many-body wave function $\Phi(r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n)$ by integrating over $N-1$ positions : $\rho(r,r')=\int d^d r_2\ldots d^dr_N \Phi^*(r,r_2,\ldots)\Phi(r',r_2,\ldots)$. It is equivalent to my second quantification formula, where $\hat \psi(r)$ is a bosonic creation operator at position $r$.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam. I am studying this ODLRO and just wanted to ask a question about your notation and to get a handle of the density matrices and reduced density matrices. Is it correct that by one-body density matrix you mean the density matrix of a pure state so that $\rho = |\psi><\psi|$ and the average being over the reduced density matrix? From this and Yang's definition (https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.34.694) (I would love to know a textbook that went more in depth with the use of these density matrices and reduced ones) we would get:
$$ <x|\rho_1|x'> = \text{Tr}\left(\hat{\Psi}(x)\rho\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}(x')\right)  = \sum_n < n |\hat{\Psi}(x)\rho\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}(x') |n> .$$
Where n denotes a complete set. So on rearranging and putting in $\rho$ we'll get:
$$= <\psi|\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}(x')\left(\sum_n |n>< n |\right)\hat{\Psi}(x)|\psi>,$$
using $\sum_n |n>< n | = 1$, we get:
$$= <\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}(x')\hat{\Psi}(x)>_{\psi},$$
with the average being a quantum mechanical average over the pure state $\psi$ and not a thermal average (although I guess it could easily be by letting $\rho = \sum_n e^{-\beta(\epsilon_n-\mu)}|n><n|$?). And then you define this as your $\rho(x',x)$?.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/372209)