# What is *diagonal* long range order?

Tags: condensed-matter, atomic-physics, terminology, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I have seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79846/) about off-diagonal long range order in superfluids.

What’s the difference and the significance between long range diagonal and off-diagonal long range order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. It means density modulation.

While off-diagonal long-range order is defined as $n^{(1)}(r,r')=\langle \psi^\dagger (r)\psi (r')\rangle$, **diagonal** long-range order is the special case where $r = r'$. Qualitatively, one can see that when $r=r'$ the argument of the expectation value is $|\psi(r)|^2$, i.e. the probability *density* of finding the particle *in space*. Hence, diagonal long-range order $\leftrightarrow$ density profile of the system.

Comment: When saying a system has diagnoal  long-range order, are we implying the density profile has some particular features?

Comment: In the context of crystals it usually means that the density has the translational symmetry of a certain lattice.