# What is the standard definition of quantum spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Tags: condensed-matter, definition, symmetry-breaking

i found many answers about spontaneous symmetry breaking [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29311/) but i am not sure to see what is the standard definition of SSB. i am interested in the BCS theory and i would like to know how the standard définition of quantum SSB applies here. what is the remaining subgroup, the order parameter, what are the off-diagonal long range terms and so on?
What do you think of the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking#Overview)?

Comment: What don't you like/understand about the other answers? Also, it would help if you narrow down your question.

Comment: The WP article is decent and sound, but you are also interested in the Higgs mechanism, operative in superconductivity, *as well* --it is the bulk of the phenomenon. [Kibble's superb summary](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism) is hard to top. I am not convinced you appreciate the logically subversive implications of "quantum". These are *all* quantum systems.

Comment: To rectify the framing of  your question, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29554/66086) smoothly subverts your implication that, somehow, the standard picture of SSB and the Higgs mechanism are not genuinely and truly summaries of the quantum situation.

Comment: there were two answers that defined SSB with entanglement. one is talking about long range effects. the other is about GHZ. i would  like to find in a textbook something like "there is a quantum SSB iff ......." and theorems that prove that other definitions are équivalent. Ane the appearance or Cooper is due to SSB according to one of these definitions.

Comment: thank you for your comments. i found the relation between odlro and superfluidity in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79846/